# The half-life $\lambda$ of a radioactive substance decaying according to the law $y = y_oe^{kt}$ is defined to be the time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The half-life $\lambda$ of a radioactive substance decaying according to the law $y = y_oe^{kt}$ is
> defined to be the time it takes the amount to decrease to $1/2$ of the initial amount %y_o%.
>
> a) Express the half-life $\lambda$ in terms of k.
>
> b) Show using your expression for $\lambda$ that if at time $t_1$ the amount is $y_1$, then at time
> $t_1 + \lambda$ it will be $y_1/2$, no matter what $t_1$ is.

I was able to do (a), and got the final expression:

$\lambda = \frac{-\ln{2}}{k}$

But I'm not sure how to do (b).

> if at time $t_1$ the amount is $y_1$

$y_1=y_0e^{kt_1}$

> then at time $t_1 + \lambda$ it will be $y_1/2$

What I did is the following:

$y_1=y_0e^{k(t_1+\lambda)}$

I replaced $\lambda = \frac{-\ln{2}}{k}$

$y_1=y_0e^{k(t_1-\frac{\ln{2}}{k})}$

$y_1=y_0e^{kt_1}e^{-\ln{2}}$

But the hypothesis was that $y_1=y_0e^{kt_1}$, so

$y_1 = y_1e^{-\ln{2}}$

Finally

$1 = \frac{1}{2}$

Which is absurd.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you say $y_1=y_0e^{k(t_1+\lambda)}$ rather than $y_1=y_0e^{kt_1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your part (a) is correct; note that $k$ is negative for an exponential decay model, thus $\lambda$ will be positive.

For part (b), if $y_1$ is the amount at $t_1$, then you correctly have $$y_1 = y_0 e^{k t_1}.$$  Now at time $t = t_1 + \lambda$, the right-hand side of the exponential decay equation becomes $$y_0 e^{k(t_1 + \lambda)} = y_0 e^{kt_1 + k\lambda} = y_0 e^{kt_1} e^{k\lambda}.$$  But we already showed $y_0 e^{kt_1} = y_1$, so substituting back gives us $$y = y_1 e^{k\lambda}$$ at time $t_1 + \lambda$.  And since $$\lambda = -\frac{\ln 2}{k},$$ we substitute this too:  $$y = y_1 e^{k (- \ln 2)/k} = y_1 e^{-\ln 2} = y_1 e^{\ln (1/2)} = \frac{y_1}{2},$$ as claimed.

Your confusion stems from setting the left-hand side of the exponential decay equation to $y_1$ at time $t_1 + \lambda$.  That's not what you should do.  The amount at this time is not $y_1$; it is some amount smaller than $y_1$, for which you need to substitute the appropriate values into the right-hand side to simplify, as I showed above.